# Page layout on meta breaks when I click "share" on an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

Something weird is happening on meta when I click on the "share" link on an answer. It only appears to affect answers and it only appears to happen on meta.

As below:

[image: answer without share popover]

Then I click on "share":

[image: answer with share popover]

As you can see, the margin to the left of the post reduces in size. Clicking "close" on the share box sets it back to its usual place.

Issue experienced on Google Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m and Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.16438.

Comment: I'm seeing it too, but only on posts that have been edited.

Comment: The share box doesn't hover above the normal page on meta like it should. Instead, it puts itself in the normal flow of the page and disturbs the other elements..

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This appears to be fixed - likely inadvertently with one of the various site redesigns over the years:

---

[image: answer without share popover]

---

[image: answer with share popover]

---

@3ventic appears to have it correct - the popover was rendering inline with the other parts of the page, instead of above or "on top" of them.